# How to show B/U (Bold Italic Underline) option on selected text in textview

Tags: swift

I want an Bold Italic and Underline option on selected text in UITextView while editing and want to get attribute string to show bold text as bold in other string.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the reference allowsEditingTextAttributes allows user to change attributes of entered text. If you want to set default attributes for text typed by user - use typingAttributes, if you want some default text shown with attributes - use attributedText property.

Comment: There is one more problem, If i get attributed string(Bold text) from textview then how can i send it to server and get back as bold attribute string.

Comment: Convert that attributed string to JSON string and check if it holds, then sends to Server.